# NGINX web-socket proxy for tcp

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy

I am new to Nginx. I am able to achieve http proxy with following config:

```
user  nginx;

events {
    worker_connections  5000;
}

http {
  upstream backends {
    server 127.0.0.1:8083;
    server 172.16.0.16:8083;
  }

  server {
    listen     12345;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://backends;
    }
  }
}
```

How to achieve similar proxy for `tcp://` or just websocket in general? proxy_pass does not accept `tcp://` or `ws://` also replacing `http {` with `tcp {` doesn't work.

Comment: See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) for proxying web socket - or [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html) for proxying at the TCP level.